# SageMaker Speed in different region

Tags: runtime, amazon-sagemaker

I am working on AWS SageMaker service.  First, I ran my notebook file under the region , "Hong Kong", this work cost me around 5 minutes. However, after I switched to "Tokyo", the same script spend 8 minutes for executing.

Does region effect script's runtime ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have anything in your code that could be region-specific? eg do you download data? where the instance types and kernels the same?

Comment: HI, Olivier. I downloaded data from local database (MySQL). And instance types and kernels are the same.

Comment: local database = in the cloud instance or in your laptop? if it's local to your laptop, the download time will be different based on the region you use (different network length to go through). I recommend you time the various parts of your code to measure what section varies with the region

Comment: Oh! I think that's the reason
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, this is no more an issue.